# Does Redhat nodeJS support async?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redhat

I have an application which runs well in Windows and Ubuntu.
But when I deploy in it Redhat system and then start, there are many errors as below:

```
.../../lib/services/utils.service.js:11
async getData(dir, subName) {
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Function._load (.../node_modules/@pm2/io/build/main/metrics/httpMetrics.js:172:43)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/../lib/apis/healthCheck-controller/healthCheck.controller.js:13:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

I have tried to remove the async,  the error disappeared and show next similar error.  however, there are many async in my code and it's terrible to replace all of them

the Redhat system is
Linux version 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-039.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) )

the nodeJS version is v11.1.0

Comment: Use Babel to transpile to code you can run anywhere.

Comment: Does this mean nodejs on Redhat doesn't support ES6,  no matter what nodejs version are using?

Answer (score 0):

this is my fault, 
it uses a lower nodeJS version locations in '/bin' rather than my installed version '/usr/local/bin'.